# Coffeescript - Nested loops

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I want to iterate over two arrays and check if the second array has any values which match the first one. I am currently trying to do it as follows, but im sure its incorrect. How can I do it ?

```
changeType = (el,shapeType) ->
 elTypes = ['circle','square','triangle']
 elClasses = el.attr 'class'
 classTypes = elClasses.split " " 

  for type of elTypes
    for types of classTypes
    el.removeClass type  if classTypes[types] is elTypes[type] 
 el.addClass shapeType
```

**[Edit]** while structure which seems to also be incorrect

```
 x = 0
 while x <= classTypes.length
   i = 0
   while i <= elTypes.length
     if elTypes[i] is classTypes[x]
        el.removeClass elTypes[i]
   i++
  x++
  el.addClass type
```

Comment: The `attr` and `removeClass` calls suggest that you're using jQuery, is this true?

Comment: yes it is true.. however, the syntax of this loop is wrong when compiled to js .. Can you be kind enough and direct me to any resoure which explains how i can iterate over two arrays and check against each of their values? I also tried using `while` structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation right here is wrong:

```
for type of elTypes
  for types of classTypes
  el.removeClass type  if classTypes[types] is elTypes[type]
```

That `el.removeClass` should be indented to get it inside the `for types` loop.

But all that is pointless busywork. [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) can remove multiple classes on its own:

> More than one class may be removed at a time, separated by a space, from the set of matched elements, like so:
>
> ```
> $( "p" ).removeClass( "myClass yourClass" )
> ```

Don't bother with the loops, let jQuery deal with it:

```
changeType = (el, shapeType) ->
  el.removeClass('circle square triangle').addClass(shapeType)
```

I think that's what you're really after.

---

I also notice that you seem to be mixing one-space and two-space indentation in your CoffeeScript. That's not exactly the best idea you've ever had. Choose an indentation amount and use it consistently in your CoffeeScript: indentation defines the structure of your CoffeeScript so you **must** be very careful with it.

Comment: Thanks sir for your honest and spot on answer! However, I am seeking to preserve the classes, but replace the shape class, ie. circle class, with the square class, for instance.

Comment: But replacing `circle` with `square` could be done using `el.removeClass('circle').addClass('square') if(el.hasClass('circle'))` so I'd still do it will jQuery rather than loops.

Comment: True, but the idea is to remove the class dynamically. Which calls for loops.. the loops are simply there to iterate of a list of classes. Have i misunderstood you ?

Comment: Maybe. jQuery doesn't know the difference between `el.removeClass('x')` and `c = 'x'; el.removeClass(c)`. And you can `el.removeClass(c)` even if `el` doesn't have the `c` class. So your whole loop is just a complicated way of saying `el.removeClass('circle square triangle')`, there classes will be left alone.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
changeType = (el,shapeType) ->
    elTypes = ['circle','square','triangle']
    elClasses = el.attr 'class'
    classTypes = elClasses.split " " 

    for type of elTypes
        for types of classTypes
            if types == type then el.removeClass type 
     el.addClass shapeType
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this still doesn't work for some weird reason. Im baffled...

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was a petty mistake.This worked of course :

```
 for types of classTypes
        for type of elTypes
            if classTypes[types] == elTypes[type] then el.removeClass elTypes[type] 
     el.addClass shapeClass
```